# When is time window reduction applicable?

Tags: vehicle-routing, dynamic-programming

Desrochers, Desrosiers and Solomon (1992) presents a method for reducing the size of the time windows for the VRPTW.

Given other versions of the VRPTW, what are the requirements on the problem for it to be suitable for this time window reduction method?

Martin Desrochers, Jacques Desrosiers, Marius Solomon, (1992) A New Optimization Algorithm for the Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows. Operations Research 40(2):342-354.
https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.40.2.342